# Why my Airlive WL1700 usb dongle won't allow more than 54MB/s?

Tags: wireless, drivers

My wireless speed is only 54 MB/s and it's not moving down or up. I've downloaded Linux drivers and got tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

The AirLive WL1700 is an 802.11g device, so the best it can do is 54Mb/sec, confirmed by Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11g-2003#Descriptions . You're limited by the hardware, and will need 802.11n or 802.11ac in all your hardware to get faster.